# generate two git patch files simultaneously without conflicts

Tags: git

My colleague and I both work on the same latest version of a branch and we are developing 
two totally isolated features, in other words, there would no any conflict/overlapping between his change and mine.

Once we both complete our features and generate the patch file against the latest version of the branch individually.  We both handed our patches to another colleague and he also has the latest version of the latest branch. Could I assume that the colleague could just apply two patches in any order/way successfully?

In other words, we don't have to rebase/merge each other's change before we make the patch file if we know those changes could not cause any conflicts. Is that correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to use patch files? - i.e. do you not have access to the / a remote? You could create an integration branch and merge both of your changes in. If there is no conflict then the merge will be trivial (i.e. no manual labour)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's as you say and they're truly independent changes, they should apply without conflicts.

The two things which are likely to cause conflicts are when both patches add to the end of a file. Or when they both add text to the same point in the file, like adding code between the same two functions.

To ensure the best chance of success, the integrating colleague should make a separate branch for each of your patches and merge them in turn.

If there are conflicts, handle them as any other conflicts.

---

Simpler is to make your repository available as a remote. This can be as simple as providing them with an ssh login and path to your repository. See [Setting Up the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) in Pro Git. You can also use this to establish a central repository everyone pushes and pulls from so you don't have to send patches around.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple because patches will use references to line numbers... that *might* have changed once one of the two patches has been applied (if you both worked on the same file, for example). The safest bet there is to have your colleague that is getting the patches to apply each one of them on a separate branch from the latest revision that you all share and then they could merge fine.

Comment: Patch can handle line number shifts. It's the surrounding context that's important.